# If and else in batch 

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm trying to make a script that will search all of the devices that are plugged into the computer and find the file common then echo back if the device was or was not found.

```
      for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
          if exist "%%d:\common\" echo Device was found on %%d: 
          )else(
          echo Device was not found
          )
      pause
```

this code doesnt seem to work though is any able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of syntactic issues in your code:

- you missed the opening brace after the if-condition (or should get rid of the respective closing brace before the `else`).
- you miss-spelled `else` (as @dystroy already mentioned)
- you need to have a space before the brace after the `else`.
- you missed the closing brace for the for-statement.

Hint: proper formatting and indenting would have hinted at some of the issues.

Your code should look something like this:

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
      if exist "%%d:\common\" ( 
          echo Device was found on %%d: 
      ) else (
          echo Device was not found
      )
)
pause
```

Comment: thank you very much for that. I am still new to batch and am self taught do you know of any good guides or tutorials i could use?

Comment: I always found [Rob van der Woude's Information](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) quite valuable.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo : Use `else` and not `esle`.

And you're lacking some parenthesis. Try :

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
          if exist "%%d:\common\" (
              echo Device was found on %%d: 
          ) else (
             echo Device was not found
          )
)
pause
```